# I want to pull data if either one of the condition is met. At the moment, it seems to be pulling data only if both conditions are met

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I want to pull data if either one of the condition is met. At the moment, it seems to be pulling data only if both conditions are met.

```
select *  FROM prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn A 
JOIN  prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_rw B ON A.OPPORTUNITYID  = B.SFDC_ID 
LEFT JOIN prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping C ON TRIM(UPPER(A.ACCOUNT_NAME)) = TRIM(UPPER(C.sfdc_account_name)) 
WHERE C.sfdc_account_name IS NULL and C.Billing_Client in ('CL.00000:')
```

Answer (score 2):

use `OR` instead of `AND`

```
 select *  FROM prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn A 
 JOIN  prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_rw B ON A.OPPORTUNITYID  = B.SFDC_ID 
 LEFT JOIN prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping C ON TRIM(UPPER(A.ACCOUNT_NAME)) = TRIM(UPPER(C.sfdc_account_name)) 
 WHERE C.sfdc_account_name IS NULL or C.Billing_Client in ('CL.00000:')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the condition in the `ON` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn o JOIN
     prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_rw orw
     ON o.OPPORTUNITYID = orw.SFDC_ID LEFT JOIN
     prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping am
     ON TRIM(UPPER(o.ACCOUNT_NAME)) = TRIM(UPPER(am.sfdc_account_name)) AND
        am.Billing_Client IN ('CL.00000:');
```

That is usually what people want when they are filtering on the second table in a `LEFT JOIN`.

Notice that I also fixed the table aliases so they are not meaningless abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OR` clause instead of `AND`

Please understand the difference between OR and AND

**OR** clause is used when we want any of the condition to be satisfied. You can use multiple OR conditions in a single SQL statement if any of the condition it will pick that record from data.

**AND** clause is used when we want all of the condition to be satisfied. You can use multiple and conditions in a single SQL statement. It is forcing to SQL statement to pick only those records which satisfies all the conditions.

Your query should be like :

```
select *  FROM 
prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn A 
JOIN  prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_rw B 
   ON A.OPPORTUNITYID  = B.SFDC_ID 
LEFT JOIN prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping C 
    ON TRIM(UPPER(A.ACCOUNT_NAME)) = TRIM(UPPER(C.sfdc_account_name)) 
WHERE C.sfdc_account_name IS NULL OR C.Billing_Client in ('CL.00000:')
```